# Accessing double pointer from a struct and using it in execvp

Tags: c, pointers, struct, double

I am trying to declare a single  char pointer and a double char pointer inside a struct like this:

```
typedef struct string3d {  
      char **x;  
      char *y;  
      } string3d;
```

I am declaring an array of this struct in my main program and then I am parsing an input of strings and tokenizing them and passing them to this structure. In the main program I call a function to create process which forks a child essentially. I am passing these string tokens to execvp like this:

```
execvp(*s1->y,s1->x);
```

Here s1 is defined as

```
struct string3d *s1;
```

but when compiled it says this:

> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your `s1` isn't a pointer ? Show us how it is defined.

Comment: s1 is defined as struct string3d *s1

Answer (score 2):

The function's signature is:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char **const argv);
```

So you have to call it like this:

```
execvp(s1->y, s1->x);
```

(Assuming that `s1` and `s2` have the type `string3d *`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have yet another question. say I want to assign 
s1.x a double pointer like *c[32]
I tried s1.x=c which doesn't seem to work. What would be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that s1 is a pointer, and not a struct. If it is a struct, then you need
s1.x and s1.y, not s1->x and s1->y.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have yet another question. say I want to assign 
s1.x a double pointer like *c[32]
I tried s1.x=c which doesn't seem to work. What would be the right thing to do?
Thanks again,

Comment: If c is a char * the correct thing to do would be &c, but its very hard to hold this discussion in comments. Please ask another question if you need a further response than this comment.